# How to append another column header and values to CSV file using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to append an extra column heading to a CSV file, and to also add a column value for each row in the CSV file.

I am able to partially get this right, but my code adds an additional header row as well. The TIMESTAMP column does not exist in the CSV file - this is the new header and column values I am trying to insert.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


# Get the list of all files and directories
path = "//wherever"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)

fields = ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3','TIMESTAMP']

for i in dir_list:
    file = path+"//"+i
    time_raw = i.split("_")
    time_compressed = time_raw[1]
    d = datetime.strptime(time_compressed, "%Y%m%dT%H%MZ")
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="cp1252", names=fields, low_memory=True)
    df['TIMESTAMP'] = d
    df.to_csv(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting this additional header is because you're using `names` inside your `pd.read_csv` call. If you want to read only the columns from the `fields` list, change the parameter `names` to `usecols`.

**For example:**

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


# Get the list of all files and directories
path = "//wherever"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)

fields = ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3']

for filename in dir_list:
    filepath = f"{path}{os.path.sep}{filename}"
    time_compressed = filename. split("_")[1]

    d = datetime.strptime(time_compressed, "%Y%m%dT%H%MZ")
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding="cp1252", usecols=fields, low_memory=True)

    df["TIMESTAMP"] = d
    df.to_csv(filepath, index=False)
```

Comment: OK, perhaps I have not described the problem sufficiently: the CURRENT file does NOT have the TIMESTAMP header/column. That is what I want to append.

If I run the code as per your suggestion, Python complains that the header does not exist. Using the "names=fields" is the only way I have so far managed to get the new column header added, but then it seems to add it twice...

Comment: @Monty ops my bad... I've edited the solution. Removing "TIMESTAMP" from `fields` should do the trick, since you'll be creating it after reading the dataframe.